# state data is undefined when modal closed

Tags: reactjs

below data load in first render but whenever i do something like click on modal box or refresh then card data become undefined and show image nodata, this data is coming from redux. anyone have any advice ?

```
function toShowCards() {
    if (props.search_stu_list && props.search_stu_list.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Cards
          oppId={oppId}
          studentProfileId={studentProfileId}
          data={props.search_stu_list}
          data1={props.opp_rec_list}
          setshowResponseAlert={setshowResponseAlert}
          setshowAlert={setshowAlert}
          setshowsentRequestModal={setshowsentRequestModal}
          // setshowBlur={setshowBlur}
          setStudentProfileId={setStudentProfileId}
          setoppId={setoppId}
          handleModal={handleModal}
          toShowblur={toShowblur}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <img className={style.nodata} src={NoData} alt="nodata" />
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, state does not get persisted automatically. If you refresh the application or undertake an action that causes the browser to refresh (like clicking on a button), you lose state data by default.

In order to persist state, you would have to make use of local storage. You could reference my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733606/persisting-the-state-of-like-button-after-refresh/70733776#70733776) to see how to use local storage. There is also a package called redux-persist that does a pretty good job of persisting Redux state after refresh. You can reference that package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist).

Comment: can i use state to store this data like `data={dataCard} data1={data1Card}`

Comment: You can store any kind of data you want. If your question is about syntax, then refer to the links I included above. I'm also happy to help if you're new to React and want to send me a link to a repo. You can add me on Discord @jevoncochran

Comment: can you give id of discord , i am not able to search with name only